# Flutter with Native Webview using OpenID Connect and Okta

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect, okta

I am currently trying to implement OpenID Connect using Okta as my identity provider.

The only plugin I found that was capable of handling OpenID Connect was the [Flutter AppAuth Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth) .
Unfortunately I was not able to use it with a Native Webview in order to have a seamless experience for the end user or more especially to not have any navbar cf. image below:

[image]

Anyone was able to implement this flow as a native Webview ?

Comment: Did you find a solution / alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you'll be able to do this in a native Webview. OAuth and OIDC are designed so the application never knows about the user's credentials - the application just receives an ID token and access token. If you tried to embed Okta (or any OAuth flow) in a native login, the application could get at the user's credentials, and possibly harvest them. Popping a browser is a more secure way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Matt's answer, AppAuth is the standard pattern here, which involves use of special InApp / system browsers:

- Chrome Custom Tabs
- ASWebAuthenticationSession

My blog has some details on this. I always recommend people to start with AppAuth samples. A couple of posts:

- [AppAuth Setup with Private URI Schemes](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/ios-setup)
- [Advanced Sample with Claimed HTTPS Schemes](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/)